# Bower.json unable to install angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, bower, bower-install

I am very very new to configuring the front end dependencies using bower or npm. I am trying to install angular-ui-router library from bower and my bower,json file looks like this

```
"angular-ui-map": "0.5.0",
"angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
"angular-ui-select": "0.13.2",
"angular-ui-mask": "~1.6.1",
```

The angular-ui-router version 0.2.15 is there detected by intellisense but when I try to restore the packages i get the following error

```
bower angular-ui-router#0.2.15                               
error Invalid       Version: 1.0.0alpha0
Stack trace:
TypeError: Invalid Version: 1.0.0alpha0
at new SemVer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     14.0\Web\External\node_modules\semver\semver.js:273:11)
at compare (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\node_modules\semver\semver.js:460:10)
```

I have been stuck on this for days just trying to set up the website for my api. Any help would be a life saver......

Comment: I just searched for "bower angular-ui-router#0.2.15 error Invalid Version: 1.0.0alpha0" and found [this bug](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2776) on their GitHub site which provides a workaround. It's always a good idea to search for the error before posting to Stack Overflow. See [ask], where there is a header "Search and Research".

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan I tried the work around it downlaods the library but then it creates some tsconfig.json file which gives further more issues..that is why i wanted to see if any one would be able resolve the issue any other way..

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it via Nuget Package Manager Console.

```
Install-Package angularjs
```

It will install all the angular modules. and you can include what you want in your Html File.